# What word from Hindu scripture translates to "demi-god"?

Tags: demi-god

The most obvious candidate "deva" is now an English word and needs no translation:

Merriam Webster:

> Definition of deva *plural -s* : a divine being or god in Hinduism and Buddhism

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_demigods),

> This is a list of notable offspring of a deity with a mortal, in mythology and modern fiction. Such entities are sometimes referred to as demigods, although the term "demigod" can also refer to a minor deity, or great mortal hero with god-like valour and skills, who sometimes attains divine status after death.[citation needed]

Since "demigod" is practically never used in Hinduism for mortal heroes - it seems have devolved into a term of denigration (minor deity) used primarily by Hare Krishnas whose works have "demigod" strewn everywhere.

Is this term of any value to translate Hindu scriptures for Hindus?

Comment: Devata or Deva is simply God.. Para Devata is Supreme God.. Demi God mite Upa Devata :P

Comment: It's the ISKCON who started this demi god, Supreme personality of Godhead, plenary portion of portion of portion of plenary portion et cetera

Answer (score 6):

Only *Upa-devatA* can translate to demi-god but not sure if this term is anywhere to be found in the scriptures at all.

Translating *Deva* or *DevatA* to simply "god" or "a divine being" or "deity" will be the correct thing to do. There is nothing in the words that translate to demi.

Those people, who started using demi-god for Deva in translations, consider Lord Vishnu as the supreme deity. But Vishnu himself is being mentioned as a "Deva" in Vedas many a times.

See the following Mantras from the Rig Veda (RV). Both these Mantras have Vishnu as their deity:

> paro mAtrayA tanvA vrdhAna,
>  na te mahitvam anvashnuvanti,
>  ubhe
>   te vidma rajasi prithivyA,
>  **vishno deva** tvam paramasya vitse ||
>
> Men do not comprehend your greatness, who is increasing with a body
>   beyond measure. We know these two heavens beginning with the earth.
>   But Vishnu Deva, you are the knower of the highest.
>
> **RV 7.99.1**
>
> trir **devah** prithivim esha etAm vi chakrame,
>  shatarchasam
>   mahitvA,
>  pra vishnur astu tavasah taviyAn,
>  tvesham hi asya
>   sthavirasya nAma ||
>
> With three steps, **this god** traversed the three earths, by his
>   greatness which has many lustres. May Vishnu, the most mighty, rule
>   over us, for luminous is the name of the firm one.
>
> **RV 7.100.3**

So, will they also translate these "deva"-s to demi-god?

Comment: Gods are also called asuras in Vedas! The meaning of words-names changes according to context. As that deva means divine being. The Vishnu who one of 33 yajna gods is a divine being.

Comment: What context? There is nothing in the Sanskrit word Deva that translates to demi.. Deva means god.. @AnubhavJha

Comment: vamana is a deva, that context.

Comment: I know demi God is false translation btw. Even supreme gods are called mahadev-adideva

Answer (score 3):

demi-God translates to devta,dev,devi,bhagvan

God translates to [ishvara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishvara),svyamabhu bhagvan, supreme being

---

For example:

you say "indra dev","indra bhagvan". But you never say "indra as [ishvara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishvara)"

but you conceptualise "vishnu" as ishvara in [smartism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smarta_tradition#Panchayatana_Puja) and [vaishnavism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaishnavism#Vishnuism_and_Krishnaism), but not in shaivism

you conceptualise "shiva" as [ishvara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishvara) in [smartism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smarta_tradition#Panchayatana_Puja) and shaivism, but not in vaishnavism

Hence, indra is demi-god in [smartism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smarta_tradition#Panchayatana_Puja) , vaishnavism, shaivism,shaktism etc(in all branches)

Comment: also related https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/368/what-is-the-difference-between-god-and-devi-devta-or-are-they-same

Comment: @S.K.: again 'it seems what you beleive as "whole of hinduism" ' is just "smartism part of hinduism' . You have to make acquaintence yourself with shaktism, where devi creates vishnu,shiva in each cycle of creation. You need to make acquiatances to pure shaivism, where vishnu is subservient of shiva, or he may not even exist separately. You may read madhvacharya's dvaitavada, where only krishna and radha exist as supreme god and vishnu is krishna's form.

Comment: Unfortunately, he targets Vaishnavas only. @zaxebo1

Comment: i am not a sectarian, i study whole hinduism. But if you will still like to qualify me, then I am sankhya follower(ie, no god) for my daily practices for now. Hence, your logic of 'Hare krishna supporters here' does not apply. The only thing is that you are refusing to see the truth.

Comment: Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuddhadvaita and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuddhadvaita#Everything_is_Krishna's_Leela
 about more such Krishna worshipping sect of vallabhacharya (1479-1531), in which Krishna is supreme. Although i am non-sectarian, but for daily practices if i personally follow (godless) sankhya, then it does not mean that I should become blind to fact that Hinduism has Pustimarga sect( **which is a major sect** ) too since 15th century, and innumerable such sects - which worship one particular deity as supreme & do not consider any other God as equal or semi-equal .

Comment: additionally i have even myself **comprehensively criticized "Hare krishna movement's mis-interpretation of Gita verse"** in **my** answer here https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26343/13287 . (but still i do not proclaim them non-hindu or bad hindu or good hindu; they are just a sect with their own worldview, just like every sect has its own)